# transaction_buffer Maximum value

Tags: singlestore

What is the maximum value that one can set for transaction_buffer inside memsql cnf?   I assume there is a correlation with RAM allocated on the server.   My leaves have 32G each and at the moment we have transaction_buffer set to 0. We are passed designing phase on our cluster and we would like to do some performance tuning and one parameter that needs to be set up accordingly is this one.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction_buffer size is an amount of memory reserved per database partition - i.e. each leaf node will need transaction_buffer size * partitions per leaf * number of databases memory. The default is 128 MB and this should be sufficient generally.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's a balancing act - data in transaction_buffer will exist in memory before being written to disk. A transaction_buffer of 0 may save you some memory, but it's not taking full advantage of the speed of being in memory. If you have a lot of databases that are updated infrequently a low transaction_buffer may be the right balance as it is a per database cost (keeping in mind that each partition is a database itself).

Transaction_buffer may also be valuable for you as a "get out of jail free" card - since if your workload becomes more and more memory intensive it's possible to get into a situation where your OS is killing MemSQL too frequently to reduce memory consumption. Once you get stuck in a vicious cycle like that, restarting with a reduced transaction buffer can reduce memory overhead enough to keep the system from being OOM-killed long enough to troubleshoot and correct the issue on your end.

Eventually, it might become adaptive, and you'll be left without that easy way to get some wiggle-room. Which is why it is essential to make sure the maximum_memory is low enough that your system doesn't begin to OOM kill processes. https://docs.memsql.com/docs/memory-management